# MySQL - Second ORDER BY Parameter in a Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Should be a pretty easy question.  Have done some research on my own, but could use a little clarification.

I have a standings table for a sports program that ranks teams in a league according to their win percentage.  Here's the bit in question:

```
// Make the query to order each team by rank:
$q = "SELECT * FROM football_1314_beacha_standings ORDER BY pct DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
```

Works fine.  However, when I have two teams that have the same win percentage, it orders them according to their primary key, which makes sense, but it is not what I want in this case.

Let's say Team A is 2-0, has a win percentage of .999% and a primary key of 1; Team B is 6-0 and has the same win percentage and a primary key of 2. I'd like the team with more wins to be listed above the other. So, I need a secondary ORDER BY condition.

I tried simply adding a comma and adding the second column name:

```
// Make the query to order each team by rank:
$q = "SELECT * FROM football_1314_beacha_standings ORDER BY pct, win DESC";
$r = mysqli_query($db, $q);
```

That works to an extent by placing the team with more wins above the other, but for some reason throws off the overall order by placing teams with the lowest win percentage at the TOP of the standings. Not sure why it does this.

Any and all advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I presume the solution would be:

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM football_1314_beacha_standings ORDER BY pct DESC, win DESC";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write desc twice. After "pct" AND "win"